# Diaplay an activity while updating Braintree nuance to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am following the following tutorial
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/ios/v4

In this I am finding issues when I post the payment nuance to server. The drop in UI remains after I enter the card details. And the options are still enabled so while the payment nuance is in progress user can select another option

Here is my code

```
BTDropInRequest *request = [[BTDropInRequest alloc] init];
    BTDropInController *dropIn = [[BTDropInController alloc] initWithAuthorization:client_TOK request:request handler:^(BTDropInController * _Nonnull controller, BTDropInResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR");
        } else if (result.cancelled) {
            NSLog(@"CANCELLED");
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        } else {
            [self performSelector:@selector(dismiss_BT)
                       withObject:nil
                       afterDelay:0.0];
            [self postNonceToServer:result.paymentMethod.nonce];
        }
    }];
    [self presentViewController:dropIn animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

In this above image I want to hide the Braintree drop in after I enter the card detail / Paypal

Thanks in advance